# Charset or Character Encoding Issue? �

Tags: php, .htaccess, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm moving my website to another hosting, because it lacks of support and has been inoperative since saturday.

On the new hosting, my website is displaying some characters as black diamonds with a question mark (�) instead of the correct symbol (á, ç, è, etc)

### HEADER CHARSET

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

### DATABASE IMPORT

It was imported using phpadmin and map charset was setted to **UTF-8**

### PHP INFO

There is no value setted to **'default_charset'** on php.ini.

### FIREFOX PAGE DETAILS

On my old hosting, Firefox Page details was reporting this encoding: **windows-1252**

On my current hosting it is: **UTF-8**

**PHP Info:**
[image: PHP Server Info]

Firefox reports the following details of page:

[image: Firfox Page Details]

### What I have tried so far

- Re-importing database using map charset ISO-8859-1
- Adding several .htaccess directives to override current charset, but
  none seemed to work (atleast Firefox Page Details never changed from
  UTF-8 to anything else)
- Changing meta charset to **windows-1252** and **ISO-8859-1**

I'm quite stuck.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using utf-8 charset, at the top of your file:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Wow, simple like that...amazing Aris!

Comment: But have I to add that to every page? Is there anyway to do it only once?

Comment: if your index page includes all others it can be added once. if you redirect to different page every time, it may be needed to add in all pages. what is your site structure?

Comment: Index doesn't includes all pages. There are several calls made to different pages. It's an osCommerce store. Anyway, I managed to fix it by adding this code to the languages page. Thanks